# VPN nameserver remains in resolv.conf after disconnecting

Tags: dns, arch-linux, networkmanager, ppp

I'm using Network Manager (1.18.0-1) on the Arch Linux system where 
 `resolvconf` is also present (from `openresolv` which is a base package `netctl` dependecy).

When I'm connecting to the VPN server via NetworkManager I'm experiencing an issue with lasting DNS record after disconnecting the VPN. I partially found why:

1. after connection the NetworkManager process includes VPN nameserver in the `resolv.conf`
2. regarding to `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/00-dns.sh` (below) and valid `USEPEERDNS=1` the `resolvconf` is called; it will make backup of the `resolv.conf` and replace with own nameserver record
3. after VPN disconnecting `/etc/ppp/ip-down.d/00-dns.sh` calls `resolvconf` to delete the nameserver record and recover the `resolv.conf` from `resolv.conf.bak` where is (at this time) unreachable nameserver record

The dirty hotfix is to disable `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/00-dns.sh` (or just comment-out the `/usr/bin/resolvconf ...` line). I don't want to uninstall `openresolv` because it will break a `netctl` dependency and I want this base package too.

Since NetworkManager is not a "stock" networking tool in Arch Linux I'm not sure if this is a kind of bug or what settings am I missing. What would be a correct way how to solve it?

> /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/00-dns.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$USEPEERDNS" = "1" -a -f /etc/ppp/resolv.conf ]; then
  if [ -x /usr/bin/resolvconf ]; then
    /usr/bin/resolvconf -a ${IFNAME} </etc/ppp/resolv.conf
  else
    [ -e /etc/resolv.conf ] && mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.backup.${IFNAME}
    mv /etc/ppp/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
    chmod 644 /etc/resolv.conf
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Interesting, 20 days and nothing ... with more points I'd start a bounty